# Is Subsymbolic AI machine learning?

Tags: data

I read a few articles regarding different types of AI.https://wiki.pathmind.com/ai-vs-machine-learning-vs-deep-learning. Here it was stated that symbolic A.I is not machine learning. So can all of subsymbolic A.I be machine learning?

Comment: yes, it is. Because, subsymbolic AI learns from data and experience, by definition.

Comment: I don't understand what the contradiction is: symbolic AI is considered not ML whereas subsymbolic AI is considered ML.

Comment: Thank you  @OmG for the answer.

Comment: Thank you @Ervan, I had asked this question as nowhere on internet did they explicitly say that all of subsymbolic AI .  I just wanted to know as im still learning through bootcamp